# Sonar issues related to at-rule @use at angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, sonarqube, scss-mixins

Getting a sonar issue
Unexpected unknown at-rule @use

When I try to add syntax like
@use 'angular/material' as mat;
Add in scss file in angular material.

Can anyone please help her how to resolve this?
[image]